# Elaborated keywords,tags,descriptions for characters in unicode

Tags: unicode

More than the official title, I'm looking for metadata per unicode point.

consider folloing characters:

```
> unicode point, name, representation, Other Keywords
> 
> U+1301E, EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH A026, , man with one arm pointing
> forward
> 
> U+263F, Mercury   ,☿, Mercury (planet) mercury (element) Hermaphrodite
> 
> U+26F5, Sailboat, ⛵, boat sail water recreation hull
```

This "other keywords" could also contain translations of logographic writing system or extensive descriptions.

This would be to make searching through the unicode character set more wholesome. i.e. search results for  "7 circles" would include ⢿ while now it says "dots".

I feel the data is there, but I need to do a lot of labor to stitch it all together from different sources. Is there a ready dataset?

Sources for now:
Official, not not very elaborated: https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-general.html#Annotations

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not clear how it’s about linguistics.

Comment: Fair enough. But I was reasoning some linguists have experience dealing with character sets and have dealt with this or will deal with this in the future.